# Laravel Multiple Cross Sub-Domain Session Sharing

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, subdomain

I have the following 4 sub-domains for my project:

`www.mysite.com` - public site, published `pages` etc.

`my.mysite.com` - normal users log in to this domain to create `pages` and other stuff

`company.mysite.com` - `Company` `hasMany` `Employees` that log in to this sub-domain to manage their `pages` and other stuff

`admin.mysite.com` - `Admin`s of the site log in here to manage everything

--

Typically, I want to keep all 4 sub-domains separate. So a user logged in to `my.` should not be able to view `company.` unless they login their as well. I have managed to do this by creating the following middlewares:

`auth:my`

`auth:company`

`auth:admin`

Using the above I have different login views/routes etc. for the different types of users working correctly.

--

I needed a way to share sessions across the subdomains because when a user creates a `Page` on the `my.`, they can publish it and it shows on the public `www.` (`www.mysite.com/my-page`)

What I needed is that when the `User` who owns the `Page` and is logged in to `my.`, visits their own page on the `www.` sub-domain, an `Edit` button to show.

I managed to do this by sharing sessions across my subdomains by making the following change:

`config/session.php`

`domain => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', '.mysite.com')`

--

However, this messes up the logins for `company.` and `admin.`, because when a `User` logs in to `my.`, the session is shared across the sub-domains.

How do I share the sessions across the sub-domains but group them so something like:

```
domain => [
    ['www.mysite.com', 'my.mysite.com'], 
    ['www.mysite.com', 'company.mysite.com'], 
    ['www.mysite.com', 'admin.mysite.com'], 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The sessions are shared because it's essentially the same application and you're presumably using `driver` = `file` or `database`.

To fix this, you can have multiple session tables per sub-domain.

1. Change your `config/session.php` file and make sure you're using `database` driver.
2. Create multiple copies of the `sessions` table, calling them `company_sessions`, `admin_sessions` etc.
3. Update your code (i.e. `config/session.php` file) so that the sessions `table` is based on the subdomain. E.g. create an `if-else` statement looking for the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and check it's a particular subdomain.

   `if ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'admin.mysite.com' ) {
       $config['table'] = 'admin_sessions';
   }`

   The layout of your `config/session.php` may need to be changed to accomodate overriding the table and returning the correct value.
4. See if it works!

There are other ways you can achieve this, but this may be the simplest.

It may not work as you're trying to share sessions and don't want all sessions to be shared at the same time. You my have to compromise on the functionality and just stick with shared sessions.